# How to search Rust recursive files with patterns?

Tags: for-loop, rust

I'm new to [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) and I was looking at [doc](https://docs.rs/walkdir/latest/walkdir/struct.IntoIter.html#method.skip_current_dir) to do a recursive listing through file and folder patterns and I'm not able to do it dynamically.

How could I make a loop containing pattern in the `is_hidden` function?

```rust
use walkdir::{DirEntry, WalkDir};

fn is_hidden(entry: &DirEntry) -> bool {
    
    let ignores = [".tmp", ".exe"]; // <<< I WANT TO ADD PATTERN
    
    entry.file_name()
        .to_str()
        .map(|s| for i in ignores {s.ends_with(i)}) 
        .unwrap_or(false) // ERROR HERE RETURN
}

let mut it = WalkDir::new("foo").into_iter();
loop {
    let entry = match it.next() {
        None => break,
        Some(Err(err)) => panic!("ERROR: {}", err),
        Some(Ok(entry)) => entry,
    };
    if is_hidden(&entry) {
        if entry.file_type().is_dir() {
            it.skip_current_dir();
        }
        continue;
    }
    println!("{}", entry.path().display());
}
```

**EDIT**

Thank you for the solution @cdhowie, but I saw the need to edit because I came across another problem.
I want to create a function that returns the files (except the ignored ones) and not just prints them.

According to the code above, I arrived at this code I'm trying:

```rust
fn finder(path: &Path) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, Error> {
    let ignores = [".exe", ".psd", ".mp4"];

    let matching_files: Vec<PathBuf> = WalkDir::new(path)
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|e| e.ok())
        .filter(|e| e.file_name().to_str().map_or(
            false, |s| ignores.into_iter().any(|i| s.ends_with(i))
        ))
        .map(|x| x.path().to_owned())
        .collect();

    Ok(matching_files)
}
```

It is not filtering according to `ignores`. I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't see the error.

Comment: Perhaps you want [`glob`](https://docs.rs/glob/latest/glob/)?

Comment: As a glob I wouldn't even know how to start :/

Comment: Do you have an example for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the lambda you pass to `.map()` in `is_hidden()`.  This lambda returns `()` because it does not return any other value. The loop and its contents are redundant; you invoke `s.ends_with(i)` and then you don't do anything with the result.

One way to do this would be to explicitly return when `ends_with` returns `true`, returning `false` if the loop ends without a match:

```
.map(|s| {
    for i in ignores {
        if s.ends_with(i) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    false
})
```

Alternatively, use the much simpler and equivalent [`any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) iterator utility:

```
.map(|s| ignores.into_iter().any(|i| s.ends_with(i)))
```

---

Note that you can combine the `map` and `unwrap_or` functions using [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or):

```
.map_or(false, |s| ignores.into_iter().any(|i| s.ends_with(i)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the solution to my problem. And you even gave me alternatives that I had never used (`any` and `map_or`) :)

Comment: Just one more question hehe, how do I return the value from the loop instead of print? I do not understand.

Comment: @littleghost `break x` will cause the `loop` block to evaluate to `x`. All `break`s in a `loop` must agree on the type, so presumably the first `break` will need to change to `break None` and then at the end you can `break Some(entry)`. Finally, you would add `let entry =` before `loop`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't resolve the loop, it's giving a type error. :/ Can I post the code here by editing the question?

Comment: @littleghost It would be better to open a new question.

Comment: Ok :) I will do this!